# Telecommute jobs in US from other country

Tags: telecommute, legal

In order to work (telecommuting) for a US-based company from another country (Spain in my case), is it necessary some kind of visa?

Comment: do you mean that you, a citizen of spain, stay in your spanish city and log in on a computer to do work in the US?

Comment: Could you clarify, are you being hired directly in the US and work from Spain?

Comment: the answer to both of you is yes xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not need a visa to work from Spain, but your employer will have to register in Spain with social security and appoint a representative, as they will have to provide for your SS coverage. As a Spanish worker in Spain, both you and your employer must comply with Spanish regulations. Make sure they are OK with that before you commit to them.

See http://www.expansion.com/2012/02/22/empleo/desarrollo-de-carrera/1329928297.html ( in Spanish)

**Edit** (as per Peter K comment) 
Please note that this answer is only relevant if you are an employee, not a self employed contractor.

Comment: That really depends on what the relationship is between yzT and their employer. If yzT is  self-employed, then whoever gives them money doesn't care anything for Spanish regulations.

Answer (score 1):

If they hire you as a contractor (not a regular employee of theirs), there is absolutely no issue. If they are hiring you as an employee, and you never set foot in the US, I think you are OK as well (but their HR department will know the answer to that definitively, and also work with you to obtain the necessary permissions).

The company may have security issues (depending on what their business is) giving you access to their networks since you are a non-US Person, but that doesn't have anything to do with visas.